# Input from external file doesn't work with Microsoft Python VS Code extension while debugging

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

While debugging, I am trying to read input from external file as advised in the VS Code docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_redirect-inputoutput-tofrom-the-debug-target) (by adding "args" : ["<", "input.txt"] to launch.json). It doesn't work as the redirect ("<") is automatically escaped (prepended with "\") by the Microsoft's Python extension (see the console output below).

```
cd /workspaces/pyt ; /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/python /home/vscode/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.7.11332232/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 41587 -- /workspaces/pyt/test.py \< input.txt
```

This way of reading input from external file does work with other VS Code extensions, for example with C/C++. Is there any way to make it work with the Python extension (while debugging)?

Comment: I submitted this question in GitHub the day before yesterday, but so far no one has dealt with it. https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/933

Comment: Than you @MingJie-MSFT. I also added a comment to a relevant GitHub issue - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13264#issuecomment-1126871014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/148887) has been solved in Vscode 1.67.2

Please update as soon as possible.